# Get All the Sibling's First Names in mySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to retrieve one or more first names from a table by performing a one to many lookup using two tables. I am able to get the siblings IDs from the second table as a concatenated column in my results but I want to get the First Name of each person with the given ID instead.

My query current query reads:

```
SELECT a.`AYSO ID`,a.`Last Name`, a.`First Name`,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`mySibID`) FROM `siblings` b WHERE b.`myID`=a.`AYSO ID`)
AS Siblings FROM `members` a WHERE 1
```

Which returns the IDs for matching `siblings` but what I want is to actually lookup each first name in the `members` table instead.

I just have no idea how to accomplish this.

Comment: each first name ??..i didnt get that part ??..you mean you want to retreive all the values from firstname ?

Comment: can you show the table structure and sample data? Or better if create a sqlfiddle.